# Rss feed not working on Chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome, rss

My Rss feed is displaying as a xml code in chrome web browser. How to solve this issue?

http://www.innovativephp.com/blog/feed/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is normal and expected behaviour. [Chrome does not have any native support for RSS.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84#c149)

Answer (score 2):

try this 5 Best Google Chrome RSS Feed Extensions....

http://www.tipsblogger.com/2010/10/rss-feed-extensions-for-google-chrome/

This should be help for you..