# Rss is not working in Google Chrome usin PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, rss

I have a problem in my code I cant understand that problem. Problem is that my code is only run on Mozila Firefox. when i try to execute it on Google Chrome its begin to download my file and not executed.

below is my code

```
<?php
include_once'connect.php';

header ('Content-Type: application/xml: charset-ISO-8859-1');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
?>

<rss version="2.0">
<channel>

<title> PACRA RSS FEEd </title>
<link> http://www.pacra.com </link>
<description>PACRA PAKISTAN </description>

<?php
$query = "SELECT og_ratings.client_id, og_ratings.press_release, og_ratings.dissemination_date, og_companies.name
          FROM og_ratings 
          LEFT JOIN og_companies
          ON og_ratings.client_id = og_companies.id
          ORDER BY dissemination_date DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("Could not execut query");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $cid = $row ['client_id'];
    $cname = $row ['name'];
    $pr = $row ['press_release'];
    $dd = $row ['dissemination_date']; 
?>

     <item>
         <title> <?php echo $cname; ?></title>
         <description> <?php echo $cname; ?></description>
         <link><?php echo "http://localhost/upload/press_release".$pr; ?></link>            
    </item>

<?php
}
?>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because chrome doesn't have an inbuilt RSS reader, you have to sue an extension.

Comment: dear actually my problem is that when i open my rss feed page chrome begin download my xml file. i want to resolve that problem :)

Comment: Please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210199/rss-feed-not-working-on-chrome?rq=1

Comment: Thank you so much :) i cant understand ur answer. but i am very thankfull to u :)